# how to install pyrocms with laravel in ubuntu16.04

Tags: laravel, pyrocms

I am currently learning about how content management system can be used with laravel and tried to install pyrocms along with Laravel.

I've tried many ways that I've found but none of them work for me.

I've visited official documentation as well https://pyrocms.com/documentation/pyrocms/3.4/installation but can't figure out how to setup.

If anyone have idea or some links then please provide some way it will be great.

Comment: Have you followed all steps from this link?: https://pyrocms.com/documentation/pyrocms/3.4/installation/installing-pyrocms

Comment: @HirenGohel I've tried but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Is there any error after the step?: `php artisan install`

Comment: @HirenGohel Composer hangs out again and again

Comment: `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
` This is the error

Comment: Is this works for you?: `pyrocms new website.dev --tag=3.2.0 --dev`

Comment: Just try this command to install it, hope it works!: `composer create-project pyrocms/pyrocms --prefer-source`

Comment: @HirenGohel I'll try

Comment: @HirenGohel   `[Composer\Repository\RepositorySecurityException]                                                                                        `   
this error encountered

Comment: See this: https://github.com/platformsh/platformsh-cli/issues/162 and in this see last answer: https://pyrocms.com/forum/channels/general/runtimeexception-when-trying-to-install

Comment: @HirenGohel still same error `[Composer\Repository\RepositorySecurityException]                                                                                           
  The contents of http://packagist.org/p/provider-2017-07%24ea8bd88d244cc5ff87ae4d01f0460492fcd08654b4436ee24f70b42c9cf79962.json do not mat  
  ch its signature. This should indicate a man-in-the-middle attack. Try running composer again and report this if you think it is a mistake  
  .    `

Comment: Hmm ok. Have you seen the last answer of **ming** from second link which i provided? He is using `pyro new` command using GIT terminal instead of XAMPP "shell".Try to see it!

Comment: @HirenGohel I'm using ubantu an here We use LAMP in terminal :D

Comment: Ohh, ok my mistake! I forgot. :D

Comment: @HirenGohel Just a composer issue, I've uninstalled my current composer and installed fresh one the problem solved. Thanks for your time :D

Comment: @HirenGohel Any way thanks man

Comment: Sorry for not discussed in chat, it's not valid to chat in messages as there's firewall in my organisation!

Comment: @HirenGohel it's okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our discussion in comments you can try to install `pyrocms` using below steps:

```
composer create-project pyrocms/pyrocms --prefer-source  

cd pyrocms

php artisan install
```

At the end you need to clear the cache of composer using

```
composer clear-cache
```

So the main problem is in the older version of composer and installing fresh composer might sort out the problem and all working fine!

Hope it might helpful to others as well!

Comment: No problem, You're welcome! I just try to fix your issue :D

Comment: At the end of the answer you can add something like, **It's a problem in the older version of composer and installing fresh composer might sort out the problem**, It might helpful to others as well :D

Comment: Never cleared cache. Anyway, to complete install Pyro, you might need to run `php artisan install`. https://gitlab.com/snippets/1666857

Comment: @Piterden you can see the comments of our discussion in the question! Hope you can see this command in it! :D

Comment: @HirenGohel it was collapsed. It is better to write this command inside the answer. Also, actually, `composer clear-cache` should be run before creating a project, not after.

Comment: @Piterden I don't think clear cache should be run before as we run it after all package installation! It should be run after we use any composer command nd then we clear the cache for composer.

Comment: You don't need to clear composer cache for use Pyro. It doesn't care about it. Composer cache is the cache of packages which would be downloaded from packagist. You should clear that cache before to get all minor changes from the main repository.

Comment: Also, `--prefer-source` is bullshit. You don't need it too. Check my answer. It is fully correct. But you shouldn't forget about requirements of L5 and Pyro.

Comment: @HirenGohel you probably mean `php artisan cache:clear`. But it is unnecessary too. Welcome to https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms

Comment: @Piterden thanks for info man! I never used pyro so i don't know more about it. I have used many packages so that i told you. Thanks for more info about pyro.

Answer (score 1):

## PyroCMS Artisan Kickstarter

### Installing Pyro

> DB should be created

```
$ composer create-project pyrocms/pyrocms
...
$ cd pyrocms
$ php artisan install
```

After answer questions and you have fully installed PyroCMS!

### Creating a module with streams

```
$ php artisan make:addon vendor.module.catalog
$ php artisan make:stream products vendor.module.catalog
$ php artisan make:stream types vendor.module.catalog
$ php artisan make:stream comments vendor.module.catalog
$ php artisan make:stream reviews vendor.module.catalog
```

### Creating a theme

```
$ php artisan make:addon vendor.theme.materialize
```

### Creating an extension

```
$ php artisan make:addon vendor.extension.product_link_type
```

### Creating a plugin

```
$ php artisan make:addon vendor.plugin.product_link_type
```

Then take a look into the addons folder

https://gitlab.com/snippets/1666857

Comment: Btw, @HirenGohel, if you like L5, you would definitely love Pyro. This is the DDD-framework, which uses meta-programming and much of programming patterns and principles in a right way.

Comment: Yes, i love laravel! Thanks for giving info :D

Comment: @Piterden maybe you know the answer to this PyroCMS question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518784/how-to-override-a-model-class-in-pyrocms-laravel-php